# Uploading image to AWS S3

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3

i am a beginner in react native. my problem is, i am trying to send image from camera to aws s3. this is my latest code.

```
import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Button, Image  } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';
import fs from 'react-native-fs';
import Buffer from 'buffer';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';



 function uploadToS3(image){
  const filename = "the_file.jpeg";
  const options = {
    keyPrefix: "uploads/",
    bucket: "this is bucketname",
    region: "this is region",
    accessKey: "this is access key",
    secretKey: "this is secret key",
    successActionStatus: 201
  }

 
  try{
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId: options.accessKey, secretAccessKey:options.secretKey, region:options.region});
    var UploadURL;
    const params = {Bucket: options.bucket, Key: options.keyPrefix+filename, ContentType: image.type};
    
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
        console.log('Your generated pre-signed URL is', url);
        UploadURL = url;
        
        
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              console.log("ok: ", xhr.response);
              alert("success");
            } else {
              console.log("no: " , xhr.response);
              alert("no");
            }
          }
        }
      
        xhr.open('PUT', UploadURL)

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', image.type)
        xhr.send({image})
            
   
    });
  
    
  } catch(error){
    console.log("err : ",error)
  }
}



class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    global.currentScreenIndex = 'HomeScreen';
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resourcePath: {},
      requestStatus: {},
      employees: {},
      response: {},
    };
  }

  cameraLaunch = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    let options = {
      title: 'Select Picture',
      storageOptions: {
          skipBackup: true,
          path: 'images',
  
      },
      base64: true,
      maxWidth: 400,
      maxHeight: 400
    };
    
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (res) => {
      //console.log('Response = ', res);
  
      if (res.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (res.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', res.error);
      } else if (res.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', res.customButton);
        alert(res.customButton);
      } else {
        
        let source = res;
        this.setState({
          resourcePath: source,
        });
        
        uploadToS3(res);
      }
    });
  }
  

  render(){
    return (

      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 100 }}>

      
      <Button
        onPress={()=>this.cameraLaunch(1)}
        title="OpenCamera"
        color="#841584"
      />
      <Text style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  {this.state.resourcePath.uri}
                </Text>

        <Image source={this.state.resourcePath} />
          </View>
    );
  }
};
export default HomeScreen;
```

there is nothing wrong with the camera or presigned url generation. if run, there will be the_file.jpeg in "this is bucket name"/uploads/the_file.jpeg, but the problem is, its size is 0 byte. i have tried to send just `image.data`, but apparently it just make the_file.jpeg become a "txt file" with "jpeg" extension. please help.

ps : i am aware on how insecure this code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed the purpose of presigned URLs which is to upload objects without the need of AWS credentials. In your example, you are initializing the S3 client using the AWS credential, in that case, you can simply use s3.upload function to upload your file.

Comment: i know the use of presigned url, and i am aware that putting aws credentials hardcoded is dangerous. im planning to move it to backend to send presigned url to frontend. the problem still the same, even if i move the presigned url creation to the backend.
i already using the upload function from aws.s3.

Comment: Ok, now I got you. So I wrote an article about signed URL with all the code snippets, I'm using the `axios` npm library as an HTTP requests library, I think it can help you. https://www.altostra.com/blog/aws-s3-presigned-url. Let me know if you have any more question or if something won't work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and nothing helped. This is what I did.

Make sure you follow the amplify guide for setting up a app. amplify init, amplify add auth, amplify push, and then amplify add storage and then do this.

```
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './src/aws-exports'
// import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
// Might need to switch line 7 to awsconfig 
Amplify.configure(config)

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [name, setName] = useState('Evan Erickson')

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    
    console.log(result) 

    async function pathToImageFile(data) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(data);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        await Storage.put(`customers/${name}`, blob, {
          contentType: 'image/jpeg', // contentType is optional
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error uploading file:', err);
      }
    }
    // later
    pathToImageFile(result.uri);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      <Button title="Upload image" onPress={() => {alert(image)}} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default withAuthenticator(App)
```